# Php loop foreach behave strange and prints out wrong html

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

I am trying to prepare email html and I have 2 groups of customers- 
1 group just will receive email
2 group will receive same email + voucher inside..
I have prepared a short code just to illustrate the problem. Here it is:

```
$voucher='<div>VOUCHER IMAGE COMES HERE</div>';//only group for voucher must see it
$mail_description='Here comes my mail text';
$voucherarray=array("mail1@gmail.com","mail3@gmail.com");
$mailaray=array("mail1@gmail.com","mail2@gmail.com");
$html='';
foreach($mailaray as $email){
$html.='<div>'.$mail_description.'</div>';

if(in_array($email, $voucherarray)){
$html.=$voucher;
echo $email.'is for voucher';
}else{ $email.'is not for voucher';}
$html.='<table><tr><td>here is some other text</td></tr></table>
<div clss="footer"></div>';
mail($email,'subject',$html);
}
echo $html.'<br />';
```

this code prints out:

```
mail1@gmail.comis for voucher
Here comes my mail text
VOUCHER IMAGE COMES HERE
Here comes my mail text
here is some other text

Here comes my mail text
VOUCHER IMAGE COMES HERE
Here comes my mail text
here is some other text
```

What is wrong with it and why it prints out  VOUCHER IMAGE COMES HERE for both mails as only one is for voucher?
Also it sends same mail to all groups users

Comment: Cannot be reproduced: http://ideone.com/hV7ilb

Comment: ^ +1. The code does not match the output in your question: http://codepad.org/ViydUkAH

Comment: yes I edited it before couple of minutes and  now must much it

Comment: @ hindmost I don't know why it doesnt work, I tested your link too but this code works on the server

Comment: Is it setup so that you mail array has ALL your addresses (both with and without voucher) and then voucher array has the ones that get the voucher? that is what you will need but your code does not seem to follow that. Also, I would re initialise the $html within the loop or else you keep adding to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need to separate between the html you send in the mail and the output you want to see for the job that sends the mail. second thing you need to empty the mail body variable after each iteration, you don't want every client to receive the mail content of the previous clients.

```
$voucher='<div>VOUCHER IMAGE COMES HERE</div>';//only group for voucher must see it
$mail_description='Here comes my mail text';
$voucherarray=array("mail1@gmail.com","mail3@gmail.com");
$mailaray=array("mail1@gmail.com","mail2@gmail.com");
$html='';


foreach($mailaray as $email){
      $mailHtml = '';
      $mailHtml.='<div>'.$mail_description.'</div>';

      if(in_array($email, $voucherarray)){
            $mailHtml.=$voucher;
            echo $email.'is for voucher<br>';
      }else{ 
            echo $email.'is not for voucher<br>';
      }
      $mailHtml.='<table><tr><td>here is some other text</td></tr></table><div clss="footer"></div>';

      mail($email,'subject',$mailHtml);
      $html .= '<br>' . $mailHtml;
}
echo $html.'<br />';
```